# Does anyone know how to get multiple download URLs from firebase storage with a single api call?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am building a web app that in some cases requires me to display multiple images on the same page. The web app uses firebase cloud storage for storing the images. In order to keep the total number of api calls down I want to get all the urls in a single call. Currently, getDownloadURL does not seem to have the ability to do this. Are there any functions you know of that do? (I know all the file paths in advance)

I tried searching for such functions on the documentation but all the docs I found only showed me how to get one url at a time.

Comment: If you understand Java, I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344799/is-it-necessary-to-create-151-connections-to-the-server-when-displaying-150-imag) will help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to request a download API for multiple files with a single call. You need at least one call for each file.

You may consider filing a feature request with the [Firebase support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report), although I must admit I haven't seen this one very often.