# listAll() function is not listing the files in a folder from the firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

The firebase database has a few folders in which I have a few audio files.

1. If I use downloadURL function and play an individual audio file using a simple toggle switch for a simple play-pause, there is no issue. (i.e., authenticated connection established with firebase from Android Studio). Here is the onViewCreated function in the particular fragment.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...

        val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        val storageRef: StorageReference = storage.reference
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        val audioFolderReference: StorageReference = storageRef.child("Daudio/file_name.mp3")
        audioFolderReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri -
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toString())
            mediaPlayer.prepare()}
        myToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener{_,isChecked->
            if (isChecked) {
                startAudio()
            } else {
                pauseAudio()
            }
        }
  }
```

[Play button for a single file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJEDx.png)

2. If I use listAll function to list the files in the folder from which I am playing the audio from the above case, the debugger shows that the list is empty.

I want to get many other details of the songs. But, for now, I am happy to just get a list of songs in the app. Here is the onViewCreated function in the fragment where I have tried to get the list of audio files from the folder in my firebase database:

```
data class GetSongs(
    var songName: String
)
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recyclerView = binding.AudioRecyclerView

        val audioFiles: List<GetSongs> = retrieveFilesFromFirebase()
        recyclerView.adapter = AudioFileAdapter(audioFiles)
        // @note: not sure if the incorrect layout affects anything here
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.context)
        
    }
private fun retrieveFilesFromFirebase(): List<GetSongs> {

        // An empty list to hold the file names
        val audioFileModelList = mutableListOf<GetSongs>()

        // Get a reference to the Firebase Storage instance
        val storage: FirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

        // Get a reference to the Firebase Storage location where the files are stored
        val storageRef: StorageReference =
            storage.reference.child("MyAudioFolder")

        // List all the files in the Firebase Storage location
        storageRef.listAll()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            // Add the names of the files to the list
            for (item in result.items){
                audioFileModelList.add(GetSongs(item.name))
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            // Handle any errors that may occur
            Log.e("Storage", "Error listing files", exception)
        }

        return audioFileModelList
    }
```

The debugger is skipping both addOnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener which is why I am thinking that the problem is with the listAll() function. I have also used security rules version 2.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.
BR,
Rao

Comment: You have to set breakpoints *inside* the callbacks if you want to be able to step through their code. The debugger will always skip over them since they are called asynchronously.  And on that point, your `retrieveFilesFromFirebase` function is always going to return an empty list because it's returning before the callback is complete. You'll have to learn asynchronous programming if you want to use Firebase APIs effectively.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the heads up! Will look into debugging asynchronous program.

Comment: As Doug commented already: Firebase APIs (like most cloud APIs) are asynchronous, because they may take some time to complete. This means that your `return audioFileModelList` is executed before any calls to `audioFileModelList.add(GetSongs(item.name))` happen, something you can most easily check by running in a debugger or adding some logging around both lines. The solution to this is to have all code that needs the URL inside the callback, be called from there, or synchronized in some other ways. I linked some questions where this was covered before.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. That is indeed helpful!

Comment: If you understand Java, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344799/is-it-necessary-to-create-151-connections-to-the-server-when-displaying-150-imag) is how you can solve it.