# Is it possible to download folder files from Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I want to download a folder with image files from the Firebase Storage, to migrate them to another hosting. But I didn't find any functionality to download even a single file in the Firebase console. Is it possible? I just need to download it on my PC, not in any script or code.

Looked through the docs but didn't find any clear instructions.

Comment: Firebase Storage is the same as Google Cloud Storage, so you can use all the same tools that Google Cloud provides.  You will want to look into a command line tool called gsutil to download the contents of a storage bucket to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for an option to download all files from a folder that exists in Firebase Storage using the Firebase Console, please note that is not possible. You can download the files one by one, but not an entire folder. However, that can be achieved using a few lines of code. For example, on Android, you can use [StorageReference#listAll()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#listAll()) which:

> List all items (files) and prefixes (folders) under this StorageReference.

This means that you can call the above method to list all files that exist at a particular location in your Storage bucket. If you understand Java, this answer will help:

- [Is it necessary to create 151 connections to the server when displaying 150 images in a RecyclerView, stored in Firebase Storage's 'Images' folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344799/is-it-necessary-to-create-151-connections-to-the-server-when-displaying-150-imag)

But instead of displaying them, you should download them.